# Is there an awesome HTML/JS editor that I'm missing?

Tags: javascript, html, editor

I'm wondering if there's an HTML/JS equivalent to LINQPad, really. Something that I could use to write some really quick disposable/portable code, without having to jump through the hoops of running our full web application in Visual Studio.

I know there's [jsBin](http://jsbin.com) and the (IMO) more feature-rich [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), but I'm wondering about a client-side application that I can use to very quickly mock-up some structure and script (mashing F5-style). Or a web-app that is a little more feature-rich and a little less prone to erase my code halfway through or want to make it publicly available. Something that auto-completes tags, shows updates on-the-fly, etc...

Anyone know of anything like that?

Comment: Thanks, but I already know and love Notepad++; it just doesn't fit this ticket. The question was directed at a more feature-rich and visually identifying editor.

Comment: What features are you looking for that you can't find in Notepad++ or one of the plugins? What is "visually identifying"?

Comment: +1. I would like the same thing. A OS app with split view that can run the code in an embedded browser or console. I don't wan't to have to create a html page every time I need to run a quick test. And tools like jsfiddle are easy to lose your work halfway through.

Comment: @Enno: Intelli(sense), I close a <tr> and am suggested a </table>, indicate that I want a table and have the basics laid out automagically, etc... As for "visually identifying", I merely meant visual feedback - a.k.a. I write code and I see what I wrote right then.

Comment: @Lance: Intellisense is usually hard, because the editor needs to understand the language and the project you are working in very well. Usually, CTAGS is the best quick-and-dirty fix that editors implement. It's built into Komodo, and there are plugins for Notepad++ that add the functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a Mac, I enjoy using Textmate.  Many people swear by it.

On Windows, I typically use notepad++.

Both of these applications are very lightweight, run smoothly, but get the job the done well and quickly.

Comment: So far, I have yet to find a suitable OS-side application that fits the bill, but I've continued using Notepad++ and hate having outstanding questions, so I guess this one has it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a big fan of [Komodo Edit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) for a lot of reasons, one of them being that it has [an Add-On for Zen Coding](http://community.activestate.com/xpi/zen-coding), which makes hacking out an HTML document a breeze.

Comment: I'm looking into this now. Sounds like it might be mostly what the doctor ordered.

Comment: Actually this seems mostly like a light version of Aptana (for what I'm using it for I guess). Aptana knows about my jQuery though. ;(

Comment: Oh, but Zen Coding is amazing! Thanks a ton for that.

Answer (score 0):

I love Emeditor which has lots of syntax files, a great support forum and autocomplete for loads of languages. And it supports UTF-8 properly if you do stuff in non-latin characters.

Also it's macro files can be written in javascript!